# Did Albert Einstein lose his Nobel Prize money on bonds that defaulted?

Tags: albert-einstein

In the book *The Gone Fishin' Portfolio: Get Wise, Get Wealthy... and Get on With Your Life*, by Alexander Green; the author states that

> *"Einstein lost his investment capital—including his Nobel Prize
>   money—on bonds that defaulted"*

Is this true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The Nobel Prize money went to his ex-wife Mileva Marić as part of their divorce settlement.

See for example [Mileva Marić (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mileva_Mari%C4%87), and [Dark Side of Einstein Emerges in His Letters (New York Times)](https://www.nytimes.com/1996/11/06/arts/dark-side-of-einstein-emerges-in-his-letters.html).

A somewhat detailed account of how the money was invested and spent appears [here](https://www.einstein-website.de/z_information/nobelprizemoney.html), but the information sources are not attributed, so take it with a grain of salt.